# How to fix "Please ensure that target device has developer mode enabled" error in Hololens Emulator

Tags: visual-studio-2017, virtual-machine, augmented-reality, hololens, hololens-emulator

The problem that I have is that after I have built my [Unity](https://unity.com/) project using [Microsoft's Mixed Reality Toolkit](https://github.com/microsoft/MixedRealityToolkit-Unity) and the Windows SDK 10.0.18362.0 I try to deploy it using the Hololens 2 emulator (version: 10.0.18362.1019). The result is that even though the emulator opens, my Unity application does not get deployed and the following error is being shown in Visual Studio's error list:

> Please ensure that target device has developer mode enabled. Could not
>   obtain a developer license on 192.168.9.57 due to error 80004005

I found several articles online that had the same problem like me, and they either [referred to resetting the HoloLens](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55382375/cannot-deploy-to-hololens-error-80004005) device (which I do not need to do, since it is an emulator) or [enabling the Developer Mode on the host machine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36324300/ensure-that-target-device-has-developer-mode-enabled-could-not-obtain-a-develop) (in my case a fully updated Windows 10 Enterprise Edition computer), which I already have. Nevertheless the error persists.

I just hope that there will be a way to get rid of this error and manage to deploy my Unity application onto the HoloLens emulator.

Comment: "host machine" is ambiguous when you use the emulator.  Ensure developer mode is enabled inside the emulator itself.

Comment: @HansPassant I edited the question and added extra information about my host machine. Regarding the developer mode on the HoloLens emulator, as you will see in this photo: http://prntscr.com/o4xr6k there is not option of enabling or disabling it inside the emulator's settings.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems that the solution is very simple. If you actually run Visual Studio as an Administrator the application is successfully deployed onto the emulator.